# Maximum lookup fields in a list

Tags: sharepoint, list, lookupfield

In SharePoint 2007, is there a limit to the number of lookup-fields that you can have in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, however you might want to bear in mind the 'rule of 2000'.

Microsoft states the following:

2,000 columns per document library and 4,096 per list

But these are not hard limits they are prformace guidelines.  You can see a full [TechNet article on SharePoint architecture and performance limitations here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

Comment: That "2000" limit refers to browsing to those lists. If you are going to use a list to e.g. hold data to be queried through an SPQuery, then this limit doesn't hold.

Comment: Hence my statement about being performance guidelines not hard limits.